# How to protect routes, not to be accessed directly through URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

```
//this route is define in app.js
<Route path="/edit" component={Edit}/>
 //this is navlink
<NavLink  to={{pathname:"/edit",state:{index:index}}}>Edit</NavLink>
 // class
class Edit extends Component {


constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {

        index:props.location.state.index,
        title:'',

    };
}

componentDidMount(){


    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/gettitle",{headers: {token: Cookies.get('adtoken')}})
    .then(response => {

        this.setState({
            title:response.data.jobs[this.state.index].title,


        })



    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })


} 
render() {

}
}

export default Edit;
```

When I click on this Navlink it moves to /edit with props, but when I directly write /edit through URL it gives errors because it is accessing /edit component without props

How can I protect /edit so that it cant be accessed directly through URL?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PrivateRoute` component:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      props?.location.state?.index ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/404" />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Here an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-ride-ie1mq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: i tried this,  props.index ? checking value is true or not but it is not checking value is defined or not .... if value of index is 0 it goes to redirect page

Comment: I edited the answer to using `state` for checking, check the example again.

Comment: how did you define  constructor and componentdidmount without class,   this.index is not accessiblle in privateRoute

Comment: Are you using [react-hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)?

Comment: So, you just need to add the code above to your class component. I just edited the answer to explain how to use `PrivateRoute`.

Comment: should i write private route Redirect part in render?

Comment: No, except the last line there. I will edit the code to determine where should use in `render`.

Comment: no, it doesnt make sense, how PrivateRoute component get this.state.index as it is not wriiten inside a class

Comment: Because I don't have your class I just have a `NavLink`. Please share your whole class in question to make a full example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212014/discussion-between-john-and-abdelrhman-arnos).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router-v3 or less you can use Route onEnter callback

```
<Route onEnter={checkIfValidUrl}></Route>
```

and in callback function you will get get replace function. which you can use to redirect to desire page.

```
const checkIfValidUrl = (nextState, replace, cb) => {
  // Your condition goes here.
}
```

But if you are using react-router-v4 or higher can create a High order component (HOC) to check if that route is valid route or not.

If your application supports server side rendering you can write code on server to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like you are using [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start), thus my answer will be for that library.

In order to protect `/edit` you could trigger `<Redirect />` if props are missing.

EditPage component would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const EditPage = ({ index }) => {
  if(index){
    return <Redirect to="/" />
  } else {
    return <div>my protected page</div>
  }
}
export default EditPage
```

Comment: what if index is not defined? how can i make sure it goes to redirect part

Comment: change `if(index)` to `if(!index)`